# install Ubuntu12.04 with ISO file using grub in usb disk

Tags: 12.04, grub2, usb

download the latest vmlinuz and initrd from

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/

I put the ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso to the /software (in my usb disk)

and put the vmlinuz and the initrd files to the / (in my usb disk)

the menu.lst for grub:

```
title Install UBUNTU SERVER 12.04 64BIT
root
kernel /vmlinuz boot=install iso-scan/filename=/software/ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso ro quiet
initrd /initrd.gz
```

I have install ubuntu server 11.10 successfully with grub for dos,but in ubuntu server 12.04, there are some wrongs:

I have boot it,and choose the language,when I click "next", it was detecting devices, then got a wrong: Can't find any ISO file to install

Comment: Why this instead of the trouble free non hardcore way of using the liveusb?

Comment: If you downloaded the kernel/initrd from `installer-amd64` why do you think you need the iso?  Why do you think you need the `boot=install`, and `iso-scan` options?  I don't really understand what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

### grub4dos

This used to work for grub4dos (e.g. hiren's boot cd):

```
title Ubuntu server 12.04.1 (GNOME 64-bit)
find --set-root /ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso
map /ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /install/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed quiet --
initrd /install/initrd.gz
```

Note that this method is **not for grub2**. Kernel line has been found in the .iso archive (boot/grub/grub.cfg)

### grub2

Follow the instructions from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

### liveusb

An alternative solution: You may easily create a live ubuntu usb using the programs:

- Startup disk creator (included in ubuntu desktop)
- LiLi (windows only): http://www.linuxliveusb.com/
- Universal usb installer (windows and linux): http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Thank you for your answer,But this method is only for desktop version, not for ubuntu server 12.04

Comment: Maybe this answer will help? http://askubuntu.com/a/126503/5538

Comment: @wurong I've changed the grub4dos solution, please try it.

Comment: @medigeek the grub4dos method only works for systems with simple/none memory management. Any modern system will ignore whatever was mapped before it took over and manage the memory on its own. To boot linux off of an iso image you either have an initrd capable of locating and mounting the image (that's what iso-scan does) or you put everything inside the initrd and forget about the iso once kernel and initrd have been loaded (thats how hiren's "mini-linux" works)